# Web-service sem IP fixo

Tags: web-service, ip

Estou estudando para criar um aplicativo Android para consumir um webservice,
por exemplo um app no Android e um em um micro o qual lê informações enviadas pelo app Android.
  Existe alguma solução para este "problema", vi algo no No-ip(DNS dinâmico), será que seria possível acessar um web-Service em um micro utilizando o No-Ip.

Comment: Precisa ser uma solução sem custo? Porque não investe em uma VPS? Existem diversas empresas com VPS's razoáveis a preços baixos (5 dólares por mês).

Comment: Interessante não conhecia o VPS, vou dar uma pesquisada e me informar melhor, mas pelo que vi é como uma VM em um servidor. pode ser uma solução!

Comment: Porque está a ser fechado como "fora do escopo"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A versão free do no-ip atualmente requer que você revalide seu host mensalmente.

Nada impede de fazer um upgrade mais tarde para um dos planos oferecidos.

Usar um webservice de um server com DNS dinâmico funciona independente do ANDROID ou qualquer outro cliente. Basta você deixar exposta a porta que deseja usar no firewall.

Exemplo: Embora a porta 80 seja padrão para HTML, você pode colocar 8888 e remapear localmente no seu server, modem ou firewal.

Para contornar esse problema de uma outra forma, bastaria contratar o serviço de IP FIXO da sua operadora, que geralmente não é caro. E vale mais a pena do que esperar a propagação do DNS para o novo IP. Que demora em torno de 30 minutos.

Comment: OK! interessante, até pensei em um IP fixo más é para iniciar estudos mesmo, até já instalei o no-IP em meu PC, e está acessando de fora, preciso ver melhor a questão das portas e o tempo de resposta. no futuro se engrenar algo creio que o melhor mesmo seria um IP fixo.

Comment: Mas não se **esqueça**, precisa entrar no site e revalidar seu host uma vez por mês.

Comment: Correto, vi isto quando criei minha conta, começei hoje a criar um Web Service pelo Net Beans pra dar uma testada! Grato!